# Access VBA Code to read a table for a file name to use in opening a spreadsheet

Tags: ms-access, vba

I have a table called FILE LOCATIONS, which has 3 fields:
Supplier (the name of a vendor)
Price List Location (the filename path, e.g. c:\users\Joe\downloads)
Price List FileName (the filename to be imported, e.g. test.xlsx

I know very little about VBA, and am reviewing tutorials online, but have a long way to go, so thank you in advance for any assistance you can provide!

I'm trying to put some vba code behind a button that will do the following:

Look up the supplier "Jones" in the table, and return the file path and name to be used in importing a spreadsheet with the TransferSpreadsheet function

Here's some code I've been trying to develop

```
Dim filename As String
Dim myfile As Variant

Dlookup("[Price File Location]", "FILE LOCATIONS", "[Supplier] = Jones"           

DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet acImport, 10, "JonesImport", filename, True, ""

Beep
MsgBox "Finished Importing Merit Price List", vbOKOnly, ""
```

Can you also recommend a good way to learn VBA, from the fundamentals to more advanced?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Text fields must be enclosed in single `'` or double quotes `"` e.g. `"[Supplier] = 'Jones'"`

See below:

```
Sub Import()

    'get concatenated file path + file name from table
    Dim filename As String
        filename = DLookup("[Price File Location] & '\' & [Price List FileName]", "FILE LOCATIONS", "[Supplier] = 'Jones'")

    'validate path
    If Len(Dir(filename)) = 0 Then
        MsgBox "File not found...", vbExclamation
        Exit Sub
    End If

    'import
    DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet acImport, acSpreadsheetTypeExcel12Xml, "JonesImport", filename, True '.xlsx

    MsgBox "Finished Importing Merit Price List", vbOKOnly, ""
End Sub
```

There are plenty of other resources on the internet nowdays from begginer to advanced level.

Good luck!

Comment: Thank you for that prompt reply!   I follow the logic, but am getting a type mismatch error on the dLookup statement line

Comment: Yep, there was an error in the path separator. Can you try now?

Comment: Perfect Kostas!  Thank you so much!   You helped me beat my deadline.  How can I thank you?  Am I supposed to vote or something?

Comment: Great, good to hear. If you are happy the answer solves your problem, accept it for reference to other users with a similar problem.

Comment: Hi Kostas, I voted, which I guess is accepting it, as I didn't see a button to accept.   That definitely solved the problem I had.   Now I've hit another snag:  the spreadsheet import has a price field with a $ sign in it and Access is interpreting this as a Text data type when it creates the table.  Is there a way I can tell it to change it to a currency field after the import, or during the import?

Comment: You can read how to accept the answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers As for the currency, you need to format the column in excel to currency before you import it. That should do the trick. If not, format the column excel as number and once imported format the column in Access table as currency.